# Android: select query in android database

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to get the values of children column corresponding to key column as in the image. What would be the select statement for it in android sqlite.

Thanks

[image]

I am using following code for it:

```
 public Cursor fetchChildren(String KEY_){
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT children FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAVIGATION
                    + " WHERE key =" + KEY_+ "", null);
                       return c;
```

But it is giving me exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: home: , while compiling: SELECT children FROM navigation WHERE key =home

           }
```

Comment: I don't know whether it is so simple or just something else then i understand your question as.Can not you use simple query method of SQLiteDatabase for fetching this column's value?

Comment: Yes i am already using that but givin g me following exception:  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: home: , while compiling: SELECT children FROM navigation WHERE key =home

Comment: try to use key='home' or key like 'home'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you just missed quotes

```
SELECT children FROM navigation WHERE key='home'
```

Answer (score 6):

As Andrey says, you need quotes around the key.

But it's better still to pass the key in separately as an argument to the query, rather than directly including it in the query. This allows SQLite to reuse the same cached query for every different key you might pass in, making it much more efficient.

```
public Cursor fetchChildren(String KEY_){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT children FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAVIGATION
                           + " WHERE key = ?", new String[] {KEY_});
    return c;
}
```